# Image upload in content type, no previous image is present

Tags: 8

Oddly worded title, I know. I'm not sure how to phrase it or what to ask exactly.

In previous versions of Drupal if I added an image field to a content type, once an image was uploaded it was saved in a library of images and it was available without being uploaded again.

Currently in Drupal 8.5.4 that's no longer the case.

[image]

I'm given the option to either upload or embed but not to select from an already existing list of uploaded images.

This is more of a nuisance since I have to reupload images even if I want to use them on a separate content type.

I'm not sure if this is a bug or it has completely changed in this version.

Drupal 8 bug tracker doesn't offer anything relevant.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That looks like Media? Is it the media browser / upload? If it is, then it should be available, but it looks like you're missing a tab that lets you select from existing.

Comment: Yes, I think it's the media browser / upload. I don't know what the module it's called. And yes, I am missing a tab. Not sure what's going on there.

Answer (score 0):

A little more configuration is necessary to add the feature of browsing existing media, you can do it with Entity browser and Core Media module in Drupal 8.5 and upwards.

Here's a great tutorial on how to do that, you need the **Part 4: How to Browse Media Assets**: [Managing Media Assets using Core Media in Drupal 8](https://www.webwash.net/managing-media-assets-using-core-media-in-drupal-8/#browse-assets)